# Can Jinn have sex with my wife?

Tags: hadith, nikah, hadith-interpretation, jinn

Can Jinn have sex with my wife? Is this hadith authentic?

“When a man has intercourse with his wife and does not name [Allah], the jinn coils around his urethra and has intercourse along with him.."

Here is a source from a islamic website:

http://eshaykh.com/family/can-a-jinn-perform-sex-with-your-wife/

Al-Hakim al-Tirmidhi [in Nawadir al-Usul, Asl 76 and Asl 207] and Ibn Jarir [al-Tabari in his Tafsir (22:248)] narrated that Mujahid said: “When a man has intercourse with his wife and does not name [Allah], the jinn coils around his urethra and has intercourse along with him. That is the meaning of the saying of the Most High: {whom neither man nor jinn has touched before them} (55:56)

Comment: Can you name the source of the hadith?

Comment: As hadith says it, and people who are well aware and have experience of the world of jinns, know that jinns can have sex with human, both males and females. And even in some cases it is reported that a jin and a human married(rare historical reports). So, yes they can.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal "And even in some cases it is reported that a jin and a human married" Could you point out such reports?

Comment: As i said these are historical reports, i ave read in some books. No one can verify them, but they are large in numbers

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

---

So, after a few days of this question and without a proper answer, i decided to gather some references which i could from internet and compile them here.

As i have said earlier in comments that i have read on many places that sex between human and jinn is possible. Even i had read some reports of jinn and human marriage. But in this question i will try to stick with sex between human and jinn. Below are things i found.

**Yes this hadith is authentic** but has different explanation by scholars. The point is all those explanations are not contradictory, so we will accept all non-contradictory explanations of all forms.

From the above source you mentioned, they quote:

**Shaykh al-Islam and true Imam, al-Jalal al-Suyuti (Allah have mercy on him) said in his book on jinns, “Ahkaam al-Jaann”** (ed. Khalid `Abd al-Fattah Shibl, Cairo: Maktabat al-Turath al-Islami, 1989, p. 24-25):

> The truth is that **it is possible for human beings and jinns to have
>   intercourse** and al-Tha'alibi mentioned [in his Tafsir] that that is
>   the meaning of {and be [O Iblis] a partner in their [human beings’]
>   wealth and children} (17:64). Al-Hakim al-Tirmidhi [in Nawadir
>   al-Usul, Asl 76 and Asl 207] and Ibn Jarir [al-Tabari in his Tafsir
>   (22:248)] narrated that Mujahid said: **“When a man has intercourse with
>   his wife and does not name [Allah], the jinn coils around his urethra
>   and has intercourse along with him. That is the meaning of the saying
>   of the Most High: {whom neither man nor jinn has touched before them}
>   (55:56)** [cf. also al-Baghawi in his tafsir under that verse].” … Ibn
>   `Abbas said: **“The epicenes (mukhannathoon) are the sons of jinns.
>   Allah and His Messenger forbade that a man have intercourse with his
>   wife during her menses; when he does, Shaytan is there before him and
>   then she may get pregnant and will give birth to a mukhannath.”**

*You can read other explanations/tafseer of these ayahs and hadees [here](https://islamqa.info/en/21946).* And they seem to tend to the other meanings than this one.

[Read this odd information](http://www.brotherrahman.net/sex-and-intimacy-having-sexual-relation-with-djinn-jinn-spirit-demon-incubus-succubus/) too, there were no apparent evidences so i didn't quoted.

And [Ibn Jebreen on sexual intercourse between a human being and a jinn [fire spirit]](http://www.islamopediaonline.org/fatwa/ibn-jebreen-sexual-intercourse-between-human-being-and-jinn-fire-spirit), this also lacks any proper evidences, but it is a proper fatwa from renowned scholar.

[From this fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=91112), as expected on this kind of issue, we find difference of opinion on this issue in scholars. Some even deny this possibility. But many(especially those with experience in spiritual healing etc) do believe in this as mentioned above.

Also this is a separate topic of human and jinn marrying each other,

**So, we can say that there is nothing definitive about this matter from quran or hadees, this is all by people's experiences and relating it with their understanding of quran and hadees. But, it's a fact that most of the people attached with this world of jinns etc do believe in this.**

---

### Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

Scientifically, it is not possible because Jinn is created from energy while human is created from mater. These two can not copulate anyways. It is all myth and baseless motion, Fake peer and Aamels spread such propaganda to exploit simple people

Comment: Do you mean Jinns can not take control over the humans and have sex with their spouse ??

Answer (score 0):

The only authenticated hadith about this issue 
"If some of you came to his family (Means wife) and saied - by the name of Allah , Allahoma , avoid us Shytan and avoid Shytan what we given - and gave a child , Shytan will not harm it." Bukhari : 3271  .

The other things like having sex with a women is not even possible due the physical existence of Jinn .

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean sheytan, and not jin. The prophet PBUH "every human being has a sheytan in their nafs", the sahaba asked" even you prophet" . The prophet PBUH  , said " yes  even me but mine has succumbed to ALLAAH  and do only good" . Whenever we do something such as eating drinking, or even have intercourse with our spouses we need to say 'BISMILAAH'  otherwise sheytan will use before us. ALLAAH  KNOWS BEST

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Consider taking our 2min. [tour] and check our [help] to learn more about our site and model. Also consider supporting your claims with evidences (see [answer]).

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned in your post, it is not considered a hadith, but the statement of Mujahid Rahimahullah. See Fathul Bari 9:229.

From hadiths in the Sahih Bukhari and Muslim, saying Bismillah and the dua before sexual intercourse is to protect from shaitaan (but it does not mean jinn will have sexual intercourse with the wife). And when the term 'shaitaan' used, it refers to any characteristics that move away people from the right path/ the pleasure of Allah. It can be from jinn and humankind. See Quran An-Naas 114:6.

May Allah protect us from anything that moves us away from deen ul Islam.