# Can human and jinn marry, and is it permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, jinn

I remember reading in many books about the human and jinn marriage and their children. But that was long time ago and i just remembered them after reading this question:

[Can Jinn have sex with my wife?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35184/can-jinn-have-sex-with-my-wife)

So, i want to know the reality of human and jinns marriage, any authentic reports about this issue. What is state of this marriage, i mean is this the marriage we know or is it something else. And is this permissible or not. Anything anyone can find will be helpful.

Comment: As you know, this is a subject with a lots of different of opinions.

Comment: @Kilise yes its because there is nothing definitive about this in quran or hadees, i just wanted to know all the existing fatawa/references on this topic.

Comment: Research on  'mugharribun'

Comment: Relevant: https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/111301/%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%B5%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%88%D9%82%D9%88%D8%B9-%D9%88%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D9%86%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%AD-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%86-%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B3-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%83%D8%B3

Answer (score 3):

### In the name of Allah, the Beneficent, Most Merciful

**All praise and thanks are due to Allah, the Lord of the worlds. We cannot find words to praise Him, as He only sees fit how laudation should be addressed to Him. We seek refuge in Allah from the evils within ourselves and the evils of our bad deeds. Whosoever Allah guides will never be led astray, and whosoever He leads astray will never find guidance. We bear witness that there is no god but Allah, the One without any associate, and We bear witness that Muhammad is His Messenger and bondman, peace and blessings be upon him, his kith and kin, his Companions and all those who follow their guidance until the Day of Judgment.**

---

**your question:** Can a human and jinn marry, and it is permissible?

**ANSWER:** The question of whether a human may marry a jinn is a controversial one.
The majority of jurists are of the opinion that such a marriage is not lawful, but some jurists consider it to be lawful. The first opinion is the more correct to follow.

Allah Says:

> "And of His signs is that He created for you from yourselves mates that you may find tranquillity in them; and He placed between you affection and mercy. Indeed in that are signs for a people who give thought." [[**The Romans, 30:21**](https://quran.com/30/21)]

Even if it could occur, it would not be possible to have that companionship and love between the spouses due to their different species. The goal and wisdom of marriage would not be attainable since the tranquility and love mentioned by Allah in the Quran would be impossible.

> "And Allah has made for you from yourselves mates and has made for you from your mates sons and grandchildren and has provided for you from the good things. Then in falsehood do they believe and in the favor of Allah they disbelieve?" [[**The Bee, 16:72**](https://quran.com/16/72)]
>
> "And if you fear that you will not deal justly with the orphan girls, then marry those that please you of [other] women, two or three or four. But if you fear that you will not be just, then [marry only] one or those your right hand possesses. That is more suitable that you may not incline [to injustice]." [[**The Women, 4:3**](https://quran.com/4/3)]

Spouses can only be from one’s own kind, since Allah Most High used the term: **“from among yourselves”.** Likewise, “Marry women” refers to females from the daughters of Sayyiduna Adam (peace be upon him), and as such, this permissibility will not be generalized to other species without a clear textual evidence. Moreover, he explains, Jinns can take different forms; hence it is possible for a male Jinn to appear in the form of a female, and visa versa. He adds from Imam Ibn Nujaym’s Al-Ashbah that marriage between a human male and a female Jinni and between a human female and a male Jinn is not lawful due to them being separate species (ikhtilaf al-jins). It was reported that Al-Hassan al-Basri (may Allah be pleased with him) was of the opinion that such a marriage is lawful so long as there are witnesses to it. However, it was later reported that he did not consider it to be lawful.

It is not permissible for man to marry an animal because they are of different species; it is not permissible to marry a jinni, either.

**CONCLUSION:** human-Jinn inter-marriages are [possible](https://eshaykh.com/family/can-a-jinn-perform-sex-with-your-wife/), but extremely rare. However, they are not permitted according to most early Muslims and classical scholars due to human and Jinns being different species and having different origins – something that would result in the marriage being void of the companionship, comfort, love and mercy mentioned by the Quran, and as such, the wisdom behind marriage would be lost.

---

**References:**

- [**May a Human Marry a Jinni?**](https://archive.islamonline.net/?p=1398)
- [**Human-Jinn Inter-Marriages**](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/5412?txt_QuestionID)
- [**Is it possible to marry jinn? If it is, is it permissible**](https://questionsonislam.com/question/it-possible-marry-jinn-if-it-it-permissible)
- [**Marriage between the jinn and humans**](https://www.jinndemons.com/marriage-between-the-jinn-and-humans/)

Comment: Why have I got a downvote?

Comment: 3 species??? devils, Jinns and Humans..... Devils aren't separate. They can be both from the Jinns and Human kind.

Comment: What is the answer: absolutely nothing that evenly remotely promotes the notion, or there are jinns that transform into humans and can marry?

Answer (score 0):

There are various opinions of scholars about this topic. For example Ibn Taymiyyah said:

> Human and Jinns can marry and give birth to a child, and that is well
> known and there are many cases of that and the scholars mentioned
> that. - [Majmo’a al-Fatawa, Volume 19 page 39]

Answer (score -1):

the marriage between a person and jinn or an animal is not jaiz.( it is prohibited and manifests itself in the HADISES)

Comment: Please cite a source for claims.

Answer (score -2):

In Irish culture we have tales of interbreeding between Faekind and Mankind, (The Fae are invisible shape shifting beings; some good, some bad; often tricksters and deceivers, the best advise is to avoid them and remain respectful when around their sacred spaces - they sound like Jinn to me).

There are some Irish today who believe they have mixed blood and a strong affinity to the unseen.